# Thin line between window decoration and launcher

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz, launcher

I did not notice until I recently changed my wallpaper, but there seems to be a thin line (maybe 1 pixel) between the unity launcher and a maximized window (see attached screenshot). This problem appears with any application. Launcher opacity is obvisouly set to 1.
I already activated/deactivated sticky edges without any effect. 
This effect is also visible using sticky edges with a non-maximized window.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you found out already, but apparently this is a design feature:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1373118 (comment #6)